# Can redux be used in application that uses Flutter Cloud Firestore?

Tags: redux, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I am currently doing some experiments with `Flutter Redux` architecture, I notice that the state of the store changes in a uni direction. 
However, in my case, I'm using `Cloud firestore`, and I am required to listen to the changes to the database on the cloud, then updating the data on UI accordingly. The code below would be in a `repository`, but I think it's not right to call `store.dispatch(updateUIAction)` in the `repository layer`. Is there a way to work around this? 
Thanks.

```
        class HikingPlacesRepository {
           const HikingPlacesRepository();

          List<HikingPlaceEntity> loadHikingPlaces() {
          List<HikingPlaceEntity> places = [];                 

          FireStore.instance.collection('hiking_places').snapshots.listen((snapshot)                  {
          print("snapshot ${snapshot.documents[0]['placename']}");
          if (snapshot != null) {
                places = snapshot.documents.map((doc) => new HikingPlaceEntity(doc['placename'])).toList();
          print("places in repo $places");
                 }
          });
          return places;
          }
        }
```

**EDIT**

After reading this [example](https://marcinszalek.pl/flutter/reduxing-flutter/), it works when using firestore in the `middleware` layer, which auto update the ViewModels when store changes.

Comment: I don't see a problem with invoking actions from the repository layer.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have add the entire repository class, actually it doesn't have access to the store, only in the `middleware`

Comment: I;m thinking about using async `Future/await` , but not sure how to achieve it in `loadHikingPlaces()`

Comment: (I don't use middleware). It shouldn't be hard to make the store available. Hard to tell from the information. It's also nit clear what problem you try to solve using async/await. https://amp.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/comments/7niro1/architecture_patterns_for_flutter/ might be helpful.